# How to get installed/not installed state of **all** packages?

Tags: package-management

I've found a bazillion references to [get a list of the installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327370/get-list-of-installed-packages), but how can I print a single list of **all known packages with their "package state"** (`not-installed`, `installed`, `half-installed` etc. [as defined by `dpkg`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/dpkg.1.html)) in a shell, ideally like this:

```
awk   not-installed
bash  installed
cc    half-installed
[...]
```

[`dpkg --get-selections`](https://travis-ci.org/l0b0/travis-ci-helper/builds/83465510#L1861-L2688) and [`dpkg --list`](https://travis-ci.org/l0b0/travis-ci-helper/builds/83469244) only lists installed packages.

`dpkg --get-selections '.'` [does *not* work](https://travis-ci.org/l0b0/travis-ci-helper/builds/83466565#L1862).

[`apt-cache dump`](https://askubuntu.com/a/220486/10371) does not print whether packages are installed, and also prints a *lot* of irrelevant stuff.

I'm using Travis CI, which is [running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server Edition 64 bit](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#Virtualization-environments) with for example [`dpkg-query` 1.16.1.2](https://travis-ci.org/l0b0/travis-ci-helper#L3945).

Comment: And what does `dpkg --get-selections` output? Why do you run it with `.`?

Comment: @Pilot6 Because the docs said it supports patterns, but apparently only patterns which start with an alphanumeric character (which sort of defeats the purpose if you're trying to list everything).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get list of installable packages from repositories?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/220478/how-to-get-list-of-installable-packages-from-repositories)

Comment: @Pilot6 [No, that doesn't seem to print whether the packages are installed or not.](https://travis-ci.org/l0b0/travis-ci-helper/builds/83472459)

Comment: So `dpkg -l` shows the installed packages and `apt-cache dump` shows all of them.

Comment: `apt-cache dump` also shows a *lot* of other package information. Not ideal, but I'm just about ready to give up on this and just brute force it with a `while read` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `dpkg-query`;

For `dpkg-query` >= 1.17.11:

```
dpkg-query -f '${Package}\t${db:Status-Status}\n' -W '*'
```

For `dpkg-query` < 1.17.11:

```
dpkg-query -f '${Package} ${Status}\n' -W '*' | awk '{print $1"\t"$4}'
```

**#1**:

- `-f '${Package}\t${db:Status-Status}\n'`: When used with the `-W` option, specifies the format of the output (see `man dpkg-query` for other options);
- `-W '*'`: lists all the packages matching the pattern `*`;

**#2**:

- `-f '${Package} ${Status}\n'`: When used with the `-W` option, specifies the format of the output (see `man dpkg-query` for other options);
- `-W '*'`: lists all the packages matching the pattern `*`;
- `awk '{print $1"\t"$4}'`: prints only the first and fourth field;

In this case it seems like you want to list the status word, so I picked the `db:Status-Status` virtual field; here are the other virtual fields related to the package status:

```
              db:Status-Abbrev
                     It contains the abbreviated package status, such as  "ii"
                     (since dpkg 1.16.2).

              db:Status-Want
                     It contains the package wanted status, part of the Status
                     field (since dpkg 1.17.11).

              db:Status-Status
                     It contains the package status word, part of  the  Status
                     field (since dpkg 1.17.11).

              db:Status-Eflag
                     It  contains  the  package status error flag, part of the
                     Status field (since dpkg 1.17.11).
```

```
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % dpkg-query -f '${Package}\t${db:status-status}\n' -W '*' | head
aalib1  not-installed
account-plugin-aim  installed
account-plugin-empathy  not-installed
account-plugin-facebook installed
account-plugin-flickr   installed
account-plugin-foursquare   not-installed
account-plugin-gadugadu not-installed
account-plugin-generic-oauth    not-installed
account-plugin-google   installed
account-plugin-groupwise    not-installed
```

Comment: @l0b0 Which version of `dpkg-query`?

Comment: Ah, I'm using an older `dpkg-query`. I've updated the question.

Comment: @l0b0 Try `dpkg-query -f '${Package}\t${Status}\n' -W '*' | awk '{print $1"\t"$4}'`

Comment: Changing `db:Status-Status` to `Status` [worked](https://travis-ci.org/l0b0/travis-ci-helper#L1861-L3944). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
dpkg-query -l '*'
```

will show you all the installed, uninstalled and half installed packages. Just grep on the package you want to filter.